# How can I post my data without generating firebase id on firebase realtime database?

Tags: json, flutter, post, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push my user's authentication id to realtime database to easily get them both in same time but realtime database keep generating id under UUID.

```
  Future<http.Response> createUserProfile(
    String id,
    String email,
    String userName,
  ) async {
    return await http.post(
      ServiceKeys.FIREBASE_URL + "/users/$id.json",
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{'name': userName, 'email': email}),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Firebase generated data tree id]

I don't want "-MCHpnJZnKvth-L89axu" to be generated. but instead directly write it into id that I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using put instead of post.
Firebase API says

> POST: Add to a list of data in our Firebase database. Every time we
> send a POST request, the Firebase client generates a unique key, like
> messages/users//

and

> PUT: Write or replace data to a defined path, like
> messages/users/user1/

Since you have the uid already, it would be a defined path

Comment: Thank you. put worked for me. I feel too bad to not able to read documentations properly. thank you for noticing me :)

Comment: Is there a way to generate the unique id or pass uid in the body of request when using POST or PUT ?